# Computing the difference of the cross-totals of the diagonals of a matrix

Tags: algorithm, c, matrix

I have solved a seemingly easy problem:

> Given a square matrix, calculate the absolute difference between the sums of its diagonals.

For example, the square matrix  is shown below:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1\, 1\, 1 \\ 2 \, 3\, 3 \\ 0\,1\,0\end{bmatrix}$$

The left-to-right diagonal = \$0+3+1=4\$. The right to left diagonal \$1+3+0=4\$. Their absolute difference is \$0\$.

However, I am a beginner in C and had some troubles. It took me way too long :D. Also, I tried to abstract the problem on a higher level - which does not mean it is high. However, I am not sure how far I should abstract the problem in such challenges.

1. How well/bad is this code written?
2. Is the code abstract enough?
3. How can you solve such challenges more quickly?

```
int addDiagonal(int from_X,int to_X,int from_Y, int to_Y, int** arr){
    int sum = 0;
    int dirX = to_X - from_X;

    if(dirX < 0) dirX = -1;
    else if(dirX > 0) dirX = 1;

    int dirY= to_Y - from_Y;
    if(dirY < 0) dirY = -1;
    else if(dirY > 0) dirY = 1;

    while(from_X != to_X){
        sum+=arr[from_X][from_Y];
        from_X += dirX;
        from_Y += dirY;
    }
    sum+=arr[from_X][from_Y];
    return sum;
}

int diagonalDifference(int arr_rows, int arr_columns, int** arr) {
    int left_to_right = addDiagonal(0,arr_columns-1,0,arr_rows-1,arr);
    int right_to_left = addDiagonal(0, arr_columns-1,arr_rows-1,0,arr);
    if(left_to_right - right_to_left > 0) return left_to_right - right_to_left;
    return right_to_left - left_to_right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How well/bad is this code written?

A good first timer implementation.

> Is the code abstract enough?

Mostly. It does make unnecessary assumptions about range.  It assumes `int` math does not overflow.

To make more abstract, code could use `typedef int TVS_int;` to ease future type changes.

> How can you solve such challenges more quickly?

Take advantage that the matrix is *square*.

With computing along the diagonal of a *square* matrix, only the matrix and its one size parameter are needed.

Use `const` to hint the the compiler about certain potential optimizations and convey code's intent better.

`size_t` is the best size of array indexing, not too wide nor too narrow.

I like the idea of using a wider intermediate type to mitigate overflow problems.

```
typedef int TVS_int;
typedef long long TVS_int2;  // a type with wider range.

TVS_int diagonalDifference_alt(const TVS_int** arr, size_t n) {
  TVS_int2 sum_up = 0;
  TVS_int2 sum_dn = 0;

  for (size_t i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    // Notice both `arr` use the same `arr[i]` --> potentially easier to optimize
    sum_up += arr[i][n-i-1];
    sum_dn += arr[i][i];
  }
  TVS_int2 diff = sum_up - sum_dn;
  return (TVS_int) ((diff < 0) ? -diff : diff);  // OF possible here in range reduction 
}
```

---

`if(left_to_right - right_to_left > 0)` unnecessarily incurs the potential for `int` overflow.  Simply compare instead.  `if (left_to_right > right_to_left)`